# Deja Dup backup at specific time of the day?

Tags: 14.04, backup, time, deja-dup

Is there a way to backup my Ubuntu machine (14.04) at a specific time of the day using Deja Dup? I'd like to backup my computer at night when I am asleep. But it doesn't seem to give a choice for the backup time.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, that answer is five years old, and appears dead. I was hoping the feature has been added by now.

Comment: Sadly not, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/479191.